# Creating step-wise function to increase x after given time intervals

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a step-wise increase in x starting from 0 and increasing by 10 every 30 seconds. I've defined time (t) as t=arange(0,120).

I looked at the Heaviside function but it did not seem to fit my need. I would need my x output to be a single value, not an array. 
Sorry if this question is basic or misunderstood - I am very unfamiliar with python.

Comment: Seems n isn't an array or list. How do you create it? And "arange" isn't part of Python's standard library. If you use an external library you should add the tag to the question.

Comment: Hi Michael, turns out I forgot to define my n as an array in the first place (stupid mistake!). That part has been resolved. Thanks for the tip about the tag, too.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to set the value at `n[0]` to `0.29`, `n` must be an array with something already at position `0`.

```
n = [0.50] #already populated list
n[0] = 0.29
```

> n = [0.29]

Alternatively, you could initialise the list with 0.29 as the first value.

```
n = [0.29]
```

> n = [0.29]

---

As for your second question, we could use a `for` loop

```
import time #module used for time functions

for x in range(0, 120, 10): #defined a range of x (0,120) with a step of 10
    print(x)
    time.sleep(30) #wait 30 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import numpy
t=numpy.arange(0,120)
x=numpy.floor(t/30) * 10
```

It can also be done without numpy using list comprehension.

```
import math
t=range(0,120)
x=[math.floor(tx/30) * 10 for tx in t]
```

Or a traditional loop for that matter.

```
import math
x=[]
t=range(0,120)
for tx in t:
    x.append(math.floor(tx/30) * 10)
```